# How to load username and email id of a logged in user on my SharePoint site on a form input field within the page?

Tags: sharepoint-server, custom-form, forms-authentication, sso, html-form-web-part

I have a sharepoint site where a person has to login using SSO ( using username/email id and passcode) to view its content. I have a form in the page where there are fields like username, email id which i need to be automatically filled with the username value for the logged in person. Can anyone share the snippet for it?

Comment: which version of SharePoint you are using?

Comment: is the username, email are people picker (Person ) field, if yes then the solution will be based on the SharePoint version you are using

Comment: SP server 2016.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1**:

You can get the current logged in user name from `_spPageContextInfo` object on SharePoint pages DOM.

**_spPageContextInfo**:

`_spPageContextInfo` is a global variable usually available on any SharePoint page. This variable stores basic information about current web and current user.

Below are the Some examples:

1. **To Get User Display Name**:

   `var currentUserName=_spPageContextInfo.userDisplayName;`
2. **To Get User Login Name**:

   `var currentUserLoginName=_spPageContextInfo.userLoginName;`
3. **To Get User Id**:

   `var userID=_spPageContextInfo.userId`

You can set these values to input textbox using JavaScript/JQuery like: [Set the value of an input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609130/set-the-value-of-an-input-field)

---

**Solution 2**:

You can also use Rest APIs to get the current user data:

```
var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/currentuser";
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    headers: {
        Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
    },
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        var items = data.d; // Data will have user object      
        console.log(items);
    },
    eror: function (data) {
        alert("An error occurred. Please try again.");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks..this was really helpful. But somehow while i consoled the _spPageContextInfo i couldn't find any parameter containing the email id albeit i could retrieve the username and user ID values.